# Get userId in jQuery weekcalendar when adding a new event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using [jQuery weekcalendar](https://github.com/themouette/jquery-week-calendar) to show appoitments in a calendar and add new ones with a simple click. In the `eventNew`  function I try to get the `userId`, where the appointment has been added. Can anyone tell me how to achieve this?

I was able to get the start and the end date of the appointment:

```
eventNew : function(calEvent, $event, FreeBusyManager, calendar) {
  var isFree = true;
  $.each(FreeBusyManager.getFreeBusys(calEvent.start, calEvent.end), function() {
    if (
      this.getStart().getTime() != calEvent.end.getTime()
      && this.getEnd().getTime() != calEvent.start.getTime()
      && !this.getOption('free')
    ){
      isFree = false;
      return false;
    }
  });

  // add the event to the database
  console.log('start of new calendar event: ' + calEvent.start);
  console.log('end of new calendar event: ' + calEvent.end);
  // how do I get the userId here?
}
```

In the [Wiki](https://github.com/themouette/jquery-week-calendar/wiki/Script-options), I found a function called `getUserId`, but I don't know how to implement this. Any help is appreciated.

Edit: The calendar is multi-user ready. Events can be set for different users.

Comment: I really dont understand where the userid comes in ? the userid of what ? does the plugin support entering events for different users ?

Comment: Yes, have a look at this demo (only on Chrome atm): http://www.slinder.ch/admin/admin/calendar/calendar.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. All these functions are called, but you have to implement them by yourself. So this code sets the `userId` of the event:

```
setEventUserId: function(userId, calEvent, calendar) {
     console.log('set eventuserid is called');
     calEvent.userId = userId;
     return calEvent;
},
```

In `eventNew` you can then call the `userId`:

```
eventNew : function(calEvent, $event, FreeBusyManager, calendar) {
  var isFree = true;
  $.each(FreeBusyManager.getFreeBusys(calEvent.start, calEvent.end), function() {
    if (
      this.getStart().getTime() != calEvent.end.getTime()
      && this.getEnd().getTime() != calEvent.start.getTime()
      && !this.getOption('free')
    ){
      isFree = false;
      return false;
    }
  });

  // add the event to the database
  console.log('start of new calendar event: ' + calEvent.start);
  console.log('end of new calendar event: ' + calEvent.end);
  console.log('userId of new calendar event: ' + calEvent.userId);
},
```